# how to sort by date inside the datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

How to sort inside a datagridview by hours? I use an XML file without format with a dataset and a datagridview.

code c# winforms :

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
ds.readXml(stream);
Stream.Close();
datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "start asc";
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Table>
  <hours>
    <Start>10:00 AM</Start>
    </hours>
<hours>
    <Start>11:00 AM</Start>
    </hours>
<hours>
    <Start>1:00 PM</Start>
    </hours>
<hours>
    <Start>2:00 PM</Start>
    </hours>


</Table>
```

on the output I have, it's not sorted.
1:00 PM
2:00 PM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM

Comment: Those are strings, not dates...

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column of type DateType and set it's expression to the name of the "start" column and sort using this column:

```
        FileStream stream = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(stream);
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Temp", typeof(DateTime), "Start");
        stream.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "temp asc";
```

Comment: I tried  but if I restart my application, I have an error message : A column named 'Temp' already belongs to this DataTable.

Comment: is it possible to remove the column added?.. I tried but no luck when I close the application.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the data is being loaded as a string and not a DateTime value.  It is sorting properly as a string. Is you want it to sort as a date, then you need to convert the data from `string` to `DateTime`. Here is an example of converting the data:

```
var accTable = new DataTable(); 

var columnSpec = new DataColumn("Date"); 
columnSpec.DataType = typeof(DateTime); 
accTable.Columns.Add(columnSpec);
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/e6b2aa61-bd1a-40f9-9e45-a538ed42c3d3

Once you convert the data, it should sort as a date.

Here is another question on SO about converting data in the datagridview:

[How to programmatically convert column type in DataGridView C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995593/how-to-programmatically-convert-column-type-in-datagridview-c)